# SQL How to convert roman number to numeral vice versa

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to convert substring in roman to numeral, vice versa.

The input data would be some kind like this:

> [image: Blockquote]

```
Input               Output
Satu I              Satu 1
Dua II              Dua 2
Tiga Iii            Tiga 3
empat Iv            empat 4
lima v              lima 5
enam VI             enam 6
Tujuh 7             Tujuh VII
delapan 8           Delapan VIII
Sembilan belas Ix   Sembilan belas 19
dua puluh xx        dua puluh 20
Dua Satu xxi        Dua Satu 21
No numeral          No numeral
No roman            No roman
```

Roman substring has inconsistent format (uppercase/lowercase/title case)

Is there a simple way to do it?

Or else (second questions), how to get the last substring from string (I, II, Iii, Iv, v, VI, 7, 8, Ix, xx, xxi) ?

I am using MySQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using switch case for each roman condition

Comment: `sqlite` <> `mysql`

Comment: *is there a simple way to do it* - are Roman numerals simple?

Comment: SQL seems like the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Your input data is in a table? or a file?

Comment: sorry, if this is a complex question, please see my second question (seems it more simple)

@MayankPorwal table with a million rows.

Comment: I wouldn't do it with SQL but rather read what I need and then get the last substring with PHP "substr('$input ', strrpos($input, ' ') + 1)" and do the conversion with PHP as well e.g. using a tool like this https://github.com/wandersonwhcr/romans

Comment: @HarryPrawiro Check my answer pertaining to your 2nd question. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find to find the last substring , do this:

```
SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(INPUT), LOCATE(' ',REVERSE(INPUT))));
```

I tested it with one of your values: Check [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aea005/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a temporary table where it Convert Suffix or Roman Numerals to numbers.

```
INSERT INTO #tmpSuffixName(
        sufCode,
        sufLetter)
    VALUES
        ('00',' '),('01','Sr.'),('02','Jr.'),('03','I'),('04','II'),
        ('05','III'),('06','IV'),('07','V'),('08','VI'),('09','VII'),
        ('10','VIII'),('11','IX'),('12','X'),('13','Sr. I'),('14','Sr. II'),
        ('15','Sr. III'),('16','Sr. IV'),('17','Sr. V'),('18','Sr. VI'),
        ('19','Sr. VII'),('20','Sr. VIII'),('21','Sr. IX'),('22','Sr. X'),
        ('23','Jr. I'),('24','Jr. II'),('25','Jr. III'),('26','Jr. IV'),
        ('27','Jr. V'),('28','Jr. VI'),('29','Jr. VII'),('30','Jr. VIII'),
        ('31','Jr. IX'),('32','Jr. X')
```

And you can execute a query like this:

```
SELECT
            @mstrSuffix = sufCode
        FROM #tmpCustomer
            INNER JOIN #tmpSuffixName
                ON ISNULL(tmpSuffixName, ' ') = sufLetter
        WHERE ID = @GetID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.uf_NumberToRoman(@NUMBER INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT @NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 3999 RETURN NULL
 
    DECLARE @ones INT = @NUMBER, @fives INT, @tens INT, @fifties INT, @hundreds INT, @fivehundreds INT, @thousands INT
 
    SET @thousands = @ones / 1000
    SET @ones = @ones % 1000
    SET @fivehundreds = @ones / 500
    SET @ones = @ones % 500
    SET @hundreds = @ones / 100
    SET @ones = @ones % 100
    SET @fifties = @ones / 50
    SET @ones = @ones % 50
    SET @tens = @ones / 10
    SET @ones = @ones % 10
    SET @fives = @ones / 5
    SET @ones = @ones % 5
    
    RETURN replicate('M', @thousands)
        + iif(@hundreds = 4, iif(@fivehundreds = 1, 'CM', 'CD'), replicate('D', @fivehundreds) + replicate('C', @hundreds))
        + iif(@tens = 4, iif(@fifties = 1, 'XC', 'XL'), replicate('L', @fifties) + replicate('X', @tens))
        + iif(@ones = 4, iif(@fives = 1, 'IX', 'IV'), replicate('V', @fives) + replicate('I', @ones))
END
go

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman VARCHAR(128), @len INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @roman = RIGHT(@roman, @len)
    DECLARE @NUMBER INT
 
    IF @len = 0 SET @NUMBER = 0
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'M%' SET @NUMBER = 1000 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 1)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'CM%' SET @NUMBER = 900 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 2)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'D%' SET @NUMBER = 500 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 1)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'CD%' SET @NUMBER = 400 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 2)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'C%' SET @NUMBER = 100 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 1)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'XC%' SET @NUMBER = 90 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 2)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'L%' SET @NUMBER = 50 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 1)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'XL%' SET @NUMBER = 40 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 2)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'X%' SET @NUMBER = 10 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 1)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'IX%' SET @NUMBER = 9 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 2)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'V%' SET @NUMBER = 5 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 1)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'IV%' SET @NUMBER = 4 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 2)
    ELSE IF @roman LIKE 'I%' SET @NUMBER = 1 + dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len - 1)
 
    RETURN @NUMBER
END
go

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.uf_RomanToNumber(@roman VARCHAR(128))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @len INT = len(@roman)
    IF NOT @len BETWEEN 1 AND 30 RETURN NULL
 
    DECLARE @NUMBER INT = dbo.uf_RomanToNumberHelper(@roman, @len)
    IF dbo.uf_NumberToRoman(@NUMBER) != @roman RETURN NULL
 
    RETURN @NUMBER
END
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a simple solution which I found at SQLROB,com, dated 2012

```
declare @RomanNumeral varchar(10) = 'LIX'

declare @Length int
set @Length = len(@RomanNumeral)
declare @Counter int = 1
declare @Character char(1)
declare @CurrentValue int = 0
declare @LastValue int = 0
declare @Value int = 0

while (@Counter <= @Length)
begin
set @Character = substring(@RomanNumeral, @Counter, 1)
set @CurrentValue =
(case when @Character = 'I' then 1
when @Character = 'V' then 5
when @Character = 'X' then 10
when @Character = 'L' then 50
when @Character = 'C' then 100
when @Character = 'D' then 500
when @Character = 'M' then 1000
else 0 end)

if @LastValue = 0
begin
set @LastValue = @CurrentValue
end
else if (@LastValue >= @CurrentValue)
begin
set @Value += @LastValue
set @LastValue = @CurrentValue
end
else if (@LastValue <= @CurrentValue)
begin
set @Value += (@CurrentValue - @LastValue)
set @LastValue = 0
end

-- For next loop
set @Counter = @Counter + 1
end

if @LastValue > 0
set @Value += @LastValue

select @RomanNumeral as RomanNumeral, @Value as 'Answer'
go
```

Can easily be used as a function or a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

My solution in MySQL, up to 3,999 (recommended: add a prefix to the name):

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS FromRomanNumerals;
CREATE FUNCTION FromRomanNumerals (
    Roman_Numeral VARCHAR(15)
) RETURNS INT UNSIGNED DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE starter varchar(2);
    DECLARE found boolean DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE dr INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0; #decimal result
    DECLARE Start_Position INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE (LENGTH(Roman_Numeral) > 0) DO
        SET found = FALSE;
        IF(LENGTH(Roman_Numeral) > 1) THEN
            SET starter = LEFT(Roman_Numeral, 2);
            IF     starter = 'CM' THEN SET dr = dr + 900; SET found = TRUE; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 3);
            ELSEIF starter = 'CD' THEN SET dr = dr + 400; SET found = TRUE; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 3);
            ELSEIF starter = 'XC' THEN SET dr = dr +  90; SET found = TRUE; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 3);
            ELSEIF starter = 'XL' THEN SET dr = dr +  40; SET found = TRUE; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 3);
            ELSEIF starter = 'IX' THEN SET dr = dr +   9; SET found = TRUE; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 3);
            ELSEIF starter = 'IV' THEN SET dr = dr +   4; SET found = TRUE; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 3);
            END IF;
        END IF;
        IF NOT found THEN
            SET starter = LEFT(Roman_Numeral, 1);
            IF     starter = 'M' THEN SET dr = dr + 1000; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 2);
            ELSEIF starter = 'D' THEN SET dr = dr +  500; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 2);
            ELSEIF starter = 'C' THEN SET dr = dr +  100; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 2);
            ELSEIF starter = 'L' THEN SET dr = dr +   50; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 2);
            ELSEIF starter = 'X' THEN SET dr = dr +   10; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 2);
            ELSEIF starter = 'V' THEN SET dr = dr +    5; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 2);
            ELSEIF starter = 'I' THEN SET dr = dr +    1; SET Roman_Numeral = SUBSTRING(Roman_Numeral, 2);
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN dr;
END;
```